# Extract Whitespace in addition to text from input file, C++?

Tags: c++

I have to write a function that will read input from a file. The file is set up: one character, space, word, space, throughout the file, like such:

`A space 1 space 2 space...` etc

I need to extract the whitespace following the one character and NOT the whitespace following the word.

How can I go about doing this? Should I just make it so the function writes the whitespace itself instead of extracting it?

Also, I am importing this info into a 2-d char array. Will I run into problems trying to write integers to a char array?

Comment: `std::cin::unsetf(std::ios::skipws)` should be a start

Comment: It's for class and we're limited to certain tools. We haven't been taught tokenization yet so I'd get in trouble for using it.

Comment: what are you saying? You can't use the standard library? It's in the C++ standard... (Otherwise, std::getline is your only viable way out)

Comment: Why would you get in trouble for using stuff you haven't been taught? What is this, sunday school? (now, being required to explain the code is entirely different matter -- you shouldn't use code you don't understand)

Comment: @Eugene: when students use code they haven't been taught, that's usually because the copied it from stack-overflow or something, without learning the material.  That's cheating.  It's also unnecessary.

Comment: @Mooing Duck fair enough for library functions I guess (which should be explicitly forbidden if that is the purpose), but wrong for concepts. There is nothing wrong with using state machine to do some hairy logic exercise that was intended to be done with bunch of conditionals for example.

Comment: I would be happy if students learned from good SO posts as long as the actually *learn* it. They're simply making you do it a specific way to verify that you learned the recently taught material.

Comment: @Eugene: Because, often, the teacher doesn't understand the more "advanced" code. And, yes, I know "advanced" is not really the proper term.

Comment: @MooingDuck that would _never_ read whitespace, unless you set noskipws

Comment: @user1362548: Reading some of the whitespace (especially if there's an unknown number of whitespace characters between) is actually very advanced.  I think you misunderstood what's required of you here.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this maybe?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    char myChar;
    char theWS;
    std::string word;
    std::ifstream in("example.txt");

    while(in >> myChar >> std::noskipws >> theWS >> word >> std::skipws) {
        std::cout << myChar << theWS << word << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes there's only one whitespace char, not sure if that's a valid assumption or not

Comment: @MooingDuck I made the assumption based on what the OP said -- "The file is set up: one character, space, word, space, throughout the file"

Answer (score 1):

You should've been exposed to the idea of a [tokenizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization) by now. This is the structure you need.

Answer (score -1):

You will be fine writing integers into character arrays. Since C and C++ represent ascii characters as small numbers anyways, handling them is easy. Some examples of the number values which correspond to specific chars: '0' => 48, '1' => 49, ... , 'A' => 65, 'B' => 66, etc.

Take a look at http://www.asciitable.com/ for the full set of ascii characters and their corresponding values.

This also allows you to perform mathematical operations on characters such as `'A' + 1 => 'B'`
as well as convert between numbers and characters `(char) 65 => 'A'`

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: _ASCII_ represents ASCII characters as small numbers. Neither C nor C++ requires ASCII to be employed here (see footnote 14 in C++11, for example); C only requires that the underlying values of lexical numerals be consecutive.

Comment: The last line of his question asks if he will run into issues writing integers into character arrays.